# How do you properly query xdb for a contact by email?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, indexing

I am trying to search an email in Sitecore Xdb  using the code :

```
var queryable = client.Contacts
                               .Where(c => c.GetFacet<EmailAddressList>(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey).PreferredEmail.SmtpAddress == emailid)
                               .WithExpandOptions(new ContactExpandOptions(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));

var enumerator = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(10);
```

But I am getting getting

```
enumerator.totalCount=0
```

I have already done this :

```
<IndexPIISensitiveData>true</IndexPIISensitiveData>
```

And

**Rebuild the xdb search index**

**I am working on XConnect Scaled Environment.**

Kindly help!

---

@x3mxray

Hi thanks for the suggestions, I changed my search query to a custom facet :

`queryable = client.Contacts.Where(c => c.GetFacet<EqContactFacet>(EqContactFacet.DefaultFacetKey).EmailId == emailid)
                               .WithExpandOptions(new ContactExpandOptions(EqContactFacet.DefaultFacetKey));`

But I am facing this error while executing the above query :

`Error in Submit ==> Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException: 
The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func 1 taskFactory)
 at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func1 taskFactory)
  at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.GetBatchEnumeratorSync[TEntity](IAsyncQueryable1 asyncQueryable, Int32 defaultBatchSize)
   at EloquaSitecoreConnector.Personalization.MergeContacts.MergeSitecoreContacts(String emailid)`

Also I have done the steps you provided, and rebuild the xdb_index as well.

Please help as this is working fine in my dev environment but not in the scaled xconnect environment.

Comment: Please make an effort to understand what this site is about. It is not a support forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query looks fine, but be sure that you did following steps:

- Enable *IndexPIISensitiveData* for **xConnect** in `xconnect.instance\App_Data\Config\Sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml`
- Enable *IndexPIISensitiveData* for **IndexWorker** in `xconnect.instance\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\config\sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml`
- Restart **xConnect** in **IIS**
- Restart **IndexWorker** in **Windows services**:
- Request xdb index rebuilding `xconnect.instance\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker>XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr`

Next navigate to **Solr** and open your `xdb_index` schema. You should see that field `facets.emails.preferredemail.smtpaddress_s` is appeared and indexed:

[image]

If you see data in Solr - you query will work fine and return coresponding results.

**Disclaimer:**

If you want to be complaint with **GDPR** it makes sense to store/duplicate PII sensitive data that you need to access by search queries in separate facet without `[PIISensitive]` attribute and dont use `IndexPIISensitiveData`, just to prevent indexing the rest of PII sensitive data.

Comment: please answer the below query @x3mxray

Comment: I have done these steps but still I am getting the count zero. I have also checked in the solr that the smtp address is indexed. @x3mxray