# How do I fix the List Manager Contact Search Not Working?

Tags: list-manager

In a Sitecore Experience Platform version 9.1.1 instance, List Manager is maintaining lists for a number of contacts.  One of these lists has 130,000+ contacts. you can see that this is working and indexed as expected when I view the Contact List Details as shown below (contact information has been blurred out):

[image]

I am looking for a specific contact that I KNOW is in this list. As an example, I can export the list to a CSV file, and I can find my contact.

HOWEVER, when using the "Search Box" in the Contact List Detail screen, it doesn't matter what I put in here, email address, name, etc.. stuff that I know is in the list... I get ZERO results. as shown in this image:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?  This is happening on EVERY list in List Manager, regardless of the size of the list.

UPDATE 1 (In Response to x3mxray answer):
I'm positive that I'm using the search correctly, here's a more concrete example.  This is a list with 3300+ contacts in it. The email addresses and last names have been scrubbed for the purpose of posting here.. but I've left the first names.

[image]

If I do a search for "ROBERT", it generates the following URL in the Network tab:
https://cm.domain.com/sitecore/api/lists/1bbd39b3-9a3d-4187-b4e2-c7a49da9fea1/contacts?pageSize=20&pageIndex=0&payLoad=full&language=en&filter=ROBERT

And the page provides the following results:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked what's in the index? And what query is sent to Solr?

Comment: Can you make sure you use the right case. I know that index is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes Index is perfect.. List Manager works correctly (the lists are usable in EXM, personalization, etc.)  It's JUST this Search box.. that doesn't return anything. I've used exact cases... and exact strings and it just returns no results.

Comment: I seem to remember there was a bug in the js code (9.0.1) that failed to implement the search filter...not sure what version it was fixed in. Does the js XHR request when executing the search include the filter param in querystring?  Is the Contact search box in EXM working? Also worth checking, are you indexing "PII" data (email etc) via the IndexPIISensitiveData config in the indexer?

Comment: Can you check network tab in Google Chrome that why it is not returning anything, could that the ajax call fails when you are doing the search.

Comment: This may not be working for the same reasons outlined in this article: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/use-the-experience-profile-search.html

Answer (score 0):

**1. PIISensitive data**

Searching *FirstName*, *LastName* and *Email* have following mapping to
XConnect contact fields:

```
FirstName == contact.Personal().FirstName
LastName == contact.Personal().LastName
EmailAddress == contact.Emails().PreferredEmail.SmtpAddress
```

In **Sitecore 9.1.1** all these fields are marked with **[PIISensitive]** attribute:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PersonalInformation
// Assembly: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 865010DA-9242-4A5D-B3EE-1E6E9A98ACA5

  [FacetKey("Personal")]
  [Serializable]
  public class PersonalInformation : Facet
  {
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "Personal";

    [PIISensitive]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

    [PIISensitive]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [PIISensitive]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [PIISensitive]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [PIISensitive]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string PreferredLanguage { get; set; }
  }


  [Serializable]
  public class EmailAddress
  {
    public EmailAddress(string smtpAddress, bool validated)
    {
      this.SmtpAddress = smtpAddress;
      this.Validated = validated;
    }

    public bool Validated { get; set; }

    [PIISensitive]
    public string SmtpAddress { get; set; }

    public int BounceCount { get; set; }
  }
```

So if you do not indexing PII sensitive information you can enabled its indexing/querying:  [How do you properly query xdb for a contact by email?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24802/how-do-you-properly-query-xdb-for-a-contact-by-email/24809#24809)

**2. List Manager contacts search with filter**

List Manager search for **exact matching** *(not substring)* of your search term with *FirstName*, *LastName* and *EmailAddress* facet values. It is not working even if you add extra whitespace in search term. And also search is case insensitive.

It works OK for me in **Sitecore.NET 9.1.1 (rev. 002459)**.
[image]
Request looks following:
`/sitecore/api/lists/{listId}/contacts?pageSize=20&pageIndex=0&payLoad=full&language=en&filter={search_term}`.

Executed filter code is (decompiling **Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.dll** from 9.1.1 installation):

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Sources.FilteringSource
// Assembly: Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 495B0D08-695A-408C-9ACC-7A79C28AD9F6

  public class FilteringSource : IContactSource
  {
    public FilteringSource(IContactSource contactSource, string searchFilter)
    {
      Condition.Requires<IContactSource>(contactSource, nameof (contactSource)).IsNotNull<IContactSource>();
      this.ContactSource = contactSource;
      this.SearchFilter = searchFilter;
    }

    public IContactSource ContactSource { get; }

    public string SearchFilter { get; }

    public virtual IContactSearchQueryFactory GetQuery()
    {
      IContactSearchQueryFactory query = this.ContactSource.GetQuery();
      if (query == null)
        return (IContactSearchQueryFactory) null;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SearchFilter))
        return query;
      return (IContactSearchQueryFactory) new AndQueryFactory()
      {
        LeftOperand = query,
        RightOperand = (IContactSearchQueryFactory) new OrQueryFactory()
        {
          LeftOperand = (IContactSearchQueryFactory) new EmailAddressMatches(this.SearchFilter, StringOperationType.IsCaseInsensitiveAndEqualTo),
          RightOperand = (IContactSearchQueryFactory) new OrQueryFactory()
          {
            LeftOperand = (IContactSearchQueryFactory) new FirstNameMatches(this.SearchFilter, StringOperationType.IsCaseInsensitiveAndEqualTo),
            RightOperand = (IContactSearchQueryFactory) new LastNameMatches(this.SearchFilter, StringOperationType.IsCaseInsensitiveAndEqualTo)
          }
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

As you can see it uses **StringOperationType.IsCaseInsensitiveAndEqualTo** operator for matching filter results.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.. see my update in the question responding to this.  As you can tell, I'm following your #2 recommendation.  Are you saying that I need to turn PII off of this field in order for Sitecore to search it?  I feel like that's incorrect.

Comment: This is also happening on three other different sitecore installs from version 9.1 to 9.3.